# Access database works fine, but compacting kills it

Tags: ms-access, crash, vba, ms-access-2013

I developed an Access (2013) application/database which is shared in a network location among several users.

The database quickly grows in size and we use Compact & Repair from time to time to reduce it. However, today, compacting made the database unusable ("ID is not an index in this table", "AutoExec can't be found", etc.). I understand it has been corrupted.

I've tried restoring older available versions but the problem persists. The thing is, **unless compacting, everything seems to be working flawlessly**.

So now I am facing the dilemma:
**Should I go back to a significantly old version or can I keep the current version and let it grow without compacting?**

Answer (score 1):

Eh... How about neither? You should track down the source of the error, and fix it. A database that can never be compacted is asking for problems.

You can remove the compiled code from forms using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897483/7296893). The *Rebuild the entire database* option described in this answer almost always fixes these kind of problems, but is pretty labor-intensive.

You can copy all database objects to a new database using a technique I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718616/7296893). However, that's less thorough than rebuilding the database, and might leave more problems existing.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to realize that rebuilding the entire database manually is my only option. But can you help me identify the problem? What does it mean exactly when the database becomes corrupted? I've tried deleting ALL the database objects and when compacting I still get the "Id is not an index in this table" error and the database becomes unusable.

Comment: @GDMM1414: Does it really matter? While you are rebuilding your application, you should **split your database** into local frontends for all users and one central backend. This will greatly reduce the chances of the corruption happening again. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913278/separating-code-from-data-in-access , also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672077/setting-up-an-ms-access-db-for-multi-user-access

Comment: @GDMM1414 the second answer demonstrates a technique to clone a database without manually copying anything. You can try omitting different objects to track down the error

Answer (score 0):

I have troubleshooted this error before. It can occur if you have a linked table to some other Database i.e. SQL Server and that table on the server gets edited (add new index, change an existing index) forgetting to refresh the connection of that linked table in Access (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledef-refreshlink-method-dao). So, to prevent this error from happening, don't forget to refresh the connection of the linked tables in your frontend, after making changes on the remote table.